# Retain 0 in front of a number

Tags: c#

I need help figuring out a logic.

I have a working code where the code will take a `string` and figure out every numbers in that `string` then add 1.

```
        string str = "";
        str = Console.ReadLine();

        str = Regex.Replace(
                str,
                @"\d+",
                m => (Double.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value) + 1).ToString()
             );
```

Example:

If I enter "User 000079 is making $1000 from Jan 02 to Feb 24".

The code will produce output: "User 80 is making $1001 from Jan 3 to Feb 25".

The problem is, I want to keep the 0 in front of the 80 and 3. (i.e. User 000080 is making $1001 from Jan 03 to Feb 25)

How do I do that?

> > Additional Info: Let me clarify, this is just an example. What I want is just a way to add 1 to every number appearing in the string. So if it means UserID, January 31 - Yes, I still want them to increase by 1

Comment: You have the length of the string matched. Use `PadLeft('0',len)` method.

Comment: str.Length will give me a length of 40. I can't seem to figure out the individual length of each number

Comment: Note that it feels like "user Id" is actually string which you happen to treat as number... Or maybe you just looking for someone to provide formatting string for you... Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I want the UserID to go through the increment too.

Comment: what happens on January 31?

Comment: It will become January 32 - which is something I want

Comment: This seems like a design flaw. You plan to increment a user ID (which should be treated as a string)?

Comment: @C.J. I meant the length of `m.Groups[0].Value` :)

Comment: What about negative values? -01 should be transformed into -02, 00 or 000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();

str = Regex.Replace(
        str,
        @"\d+",
        m => (Double.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(m.Groups[0].Value.Length, '0')
        );
```

Comment: I think Dick van den Brink's final answer is better: it parses as `int` instead of `double` and the `ToString` formatting probably is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with the ToString format like below:

```
String x = (50).ToString("D8"); // "00000050"
```

You can find more info about this here: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx)

edit: About the lengte if you do this the length will be correct:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
                str,
                @"\d+",
                m => (int.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value) + 1).ToString("D" + m.Groups[0].Value.Length)
             );
```

Comment: It seems the number of digits is totally variable, so I guess this can't be applied in his case.

Comment: I did try several methods like this, but like @Andrew said, the length of the digit is completely variable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your user ID numbers aren't really 'numbers', but rather strings of numeric characters.  Can the representation of the ID be changed to a string instead?

If you only care about the extra zeroes when rendering the ID, you can use `String.Format` to render the numeric value correctly using [Custom Numeric Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) (specifically, see the '[Zero Placeholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#Specifier0)' section).